# Key ideas behind p-adic Baker's theorem

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis, transcendental-number-theory

I'm trying to understand Kunrui Yu's series of papers [[1](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1990__74_1_15_0) [2](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485892740) [3](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/FORUM.2007.009/html)] on lower bounds of linear forms of p-adic logarithms (i.e., p-adic Baker's theorem). I know the proof of the usual Baker's theorem through excellent resources like [Terence Tao's blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/), or [Soundararajan's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eksound/TransNotes.pdf). I'm wonder if anyone knows similar digests or sketches for Yu's bounds, especially for someone who just wants to know the key ideas that are required specifically for the p-adic case. This can be either some pdf somewhere, or as a direct answer to this question.

Thanks in advance!